# How to read values form a properties file and store in a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a properties file which has following key values pairs:

```
version 1 = test
version 2 = qa
version 3 = prd
```

I want to use these values in a variable in Batch file.

I am using a for loop command in DOS for the same but it is taking the last value of `version` i.e `prd` (`version 3`).

The following is the code:

```
set total=3
for /f %%a in (1 2 %total%) do (
    echo %%a
    FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,2 delims==" %%i IN ('findstr /i "version%%a" test.txt') DO (
        set version%%a=%%i
    )
)
```

All the variables `version 1` , `version 2` and `version 3` take the value `prd`.

Can someone provide a solution for this?

Comment: The file is test.txt and not a properties file :)

Comment: Are you really on DOS, or are you using Windows? Is there really only one line in your example text file, or are there 3 lines (one per name, value pair)? Your 1st FOR loop makes no sense - As written it is looking for files named 1, 2 and 3 and processing the contents. You should better describe what results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to store the value of each version in different variables  namely version1 version2 and so . And i am working on windows only..
Sry for that dos tag

As far as file is concerned it contains 3 lines one per name value pair..

Comment: I edited your text file. You can edit your own question by using the "edit" link just above the comment section on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You need to review the documentation for the FOR command (type HELP FOR). There are lots of variations that look similar, yet behave differently. I don't see how the code you posted could give the results you describe, but anyway...

If your text file is named "test.txt" and its contents look like the following

```
version1=test
version2=qa
version3=prd
```

then it would be simple to get your 3 variables as you want them.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in (test.txt) do set %%A
```

But your file has extra spaces that I don't think you want. There would be spaces in the variable names, as well as a leading space in each value. I think the following will give what you are looking for. It will eliminate spaces from the variable names and also eliminate leading spaces from the values.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (test.txt) do (
  set name=%%A
  set "name=!name: =!"
  for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ("%%B") do set "!name!=%%C"
)
set version
```

Running the above script against this text file:

```
version 1 = test
version2=qa
 version 3 = two words
version 4 = a = b
```

gives these results:

```
version1=test
version2=qa
version3=two words
version4=a = b
```

Comment: Please suggest required changes, if output required is test for echo !version1!, and qa for echo !version2!. Thanks